# Receive index of list element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, indexing

i have an unordered list with an unknown number of list items. it looks like this:

```
<ul id="keyvisualpager">
    <li><a><span>first</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>second</span></a></li>
    <li><a><span>third</span></a></li>              
    <li><a><span>and so on</span></a></li>              
    <li><a><span>fsdfsf</span></a></li>             
    <li><a><span>asdad</span></a></li>              
</ul>
```

when the user clicks on a link, i need to find out the index of the list element and assign it to a variable. e.g. if the user is clicking the second link ("second") the variable should be set to "2"...

```
$('#keyvisualpager li a').click(function () { 

     // receive index of list element
     var mbr_index = ???;   


});
```

i have to use jquery 1.2.1 ... so no fancy stuff please :)

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you overlooked that [`.index(element)` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/index/) was already available in jQuery 1.0:

```
var $items = $('#keyvisualpager li');

$items.find('a').click(function () { 
     var mbr_index = $items.index($(this).parent()) + 1; // one based index
});
```

---

**Original answer:**

This should work in jQuery 1.2:

```
var mbr_index = $(this).parent().prevAll().length + 1; // one based index
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider assigning the click a little more manually using `each()`. You can iterate over the list items and have the index available to you. You can find the anchor within the list item and bind its click method.

```
$('#keyvisualpager li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('a').bind('click', function() {
        var mbr_index = index + 1; // indices start at 0
        ...
    });
});
```

`each()` was available in jQuery 1.0 so you should be able to use it no problem.